# Implementing a Generic View Table Content ASP Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am trying to build a web page that returns all columns in any table (audit tables) a user selects. Suppose I have 4 audit tables in my database namely `CustomerAudit`, `VendorAudit`, `InvoiceAudit` and `PaymentAudit` each with a different table structure.

On a webpage, probably using a dropdownlist, a user should be able to select any of the four and the content of the selected table appears in a grid below the dropdownlist.

The table list in the dropdownlist could change. But when it changes, user should be able to view the content in the gridview.

How can I achieve this? The project implements a 3-tier EF, DTO, BL (WCF), UI (Web forms).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We do this all the time using third-party grid controls.

The basic flow is:

1) The user selects a value from the dropdown list.

2) The user optionally presses a refresh button (we implement this approach because the user may want to just refresh the data for the selected table type).

3) The page is posted back

4) The appropriate data is retrieved

5) The columns for the grid are constructed according to the selected table type, first removing any previous columns.

6) The data is bound to the grid.

Note that depending on the exact implementation of the grid, items 5 and 6 may need to be swapped.